# Express routing -- 404 error when routing to /secrets, what am I missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, http-status-code-404

I have an express app setup but I can't figure out how to make it route correctly. At the moment I have this in app.js:

```
var secrets = require('./routes/secrets');
var app = express();

app.use('secrets', secrets);
```

The following in /routes/secrets.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET 'secrets' */
router.get('/secrets', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('secrets', { title: 'Colour Hack v1.1' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The file /views/secrets.jade contains the following code:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 A Very Green Affair
  p It began at a Green Party hustings. I was wearing a beige trenchcoat, set off perfectly by an exquisitely cut Fedora, tailored by the finest vegan outfitters a party councilor's allowance can buy. We locked eyes over the pay-what-you-like FoodCycle buffet and I knew right then something special was about to occur. Amelia Womack wore a pant-suit and has a really nice hair-style. Once she noticed me she approached immediately.
  p "Hi Amy."
  p She said, though it appeared as if the name was somehow unfamiliar to her, and she looked into my eyes with the sort of intensity you might expect of a fawn who's just single-handedly decimated a pack of ravaging wolves and has rounded on the ring-leader who has unexpectedly turned out to be another fawn with particularly big teeth and wolf-like fur who had managed to convince the wolves it was one of them.
  p "It's strange I should run into you as I was just thinking about that... policy suggestion you made."
  p Amelia said the word 'that' with an odd intonation, so it seemed almost as if she were thinking about something other than the policy document. Something secret.
  p "The cat policy," I replied, my words sounding both artful and powerful as I spoke them, and considered her choice of blusher, which seemed a particularly deep red, so that it underscored her already stunning features with a power and authority that lost nothing of femininity. Amelia noticed a kind of damp feeling and wondered if she should have brought a change of underwear but she carried on in a business-like, official sort of way which also seemed to tred a strangely fine line between school-girlish and teacherly.
  p "Yes, Amy, the cat policy. We really need to talk about the cats, don't we..."
```

But at the moment I'm just getting a 404 error when I type /secrets into the browser, after the root URL. Can anyone tell me how I can approach this differently so I register a successful GET request and properly serve the page?

Comment: It could be crashing because of a syntax error in `/routes/secrets.js`, it should be `res.render('secrets', {title: 'Colour Hack v1.1});`

Comment: @DrakaSAN Thanks. I'll change that see if it helps any :)... no; I have that right in the file. Just a transcription error on my part there, sorry DranSAN :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a '/' to your request url in app.js: `app.use('/secrets', secrets)`

Now you still define to use "/secrets/secrets" as GET, because
the setting of the Router appends this request url from app.js.

Change the request url for the Router to only `/` like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {} );
```

Comment: Thanks Hardi. I tried that but it's still not working right now. Is there a way I can track what's actually being requested in the browser maybe? I'm using Iceweasel which is basically Firefox I think.

Comment: Nevermind. I restarted the server and now it works fine. Thanks!